# Polychoric Correlation with pvalue in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a polychoric correlation in R and obtain its p value. I have been using the following code:

```
library(polycor)
polychor(x,y)
```

While it provides me with the value of the correlation, I still need the pvalue, Is there any way to obtain it using this function? or should I use another function?

Thank you!

Comment: What test are you seeking the p-value for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what test you are seeking exactly.

However, if you set `std.err` to `TRUE` you get the test of bivariate normality. Is that what you are after?

```
library(polycor)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- runif(10)
ans <- polychor(x, y, std.err=TRUE)
print(ans)
#
#Polychoric Correlation, 2-step est. = 0.2633 (0.3001)
#Test of bivariate normality: Chisquare = 45.39, df = 80, p = 0.9994
```

Run `?polychor` for more information.

You can extract the p-value using:

```
pchisq(ans$chisq, ans$df, lower.tail = FALSE)
#0.9994
```